Example of continuous function without lifting
I have seen the following theorem in class:
Theorem: Let $\rho: \hat{X}\rightarrow X$ be a covering map, $x_0\in X, \ \hat{x}_0\in \rho^{-1}(x_0)$, $f:Y\rightarrow X$ continuous with  $  y_0\in Y$ such that $f(y_0)=x_0$ and $Y$ connected and locally arcwise connected. If $f_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0))\subset \rho_*(\pi_1(\hat{X},\hat{x}_0))$ then there exists only one $\hat{f}:Y\rightarrow\hat{X}$ such that $\rho \circ \hat{f}=f$ and $\hat{f}(y_0)=\hat{x}_0$.
If $Y$ is simply connected and locally arcwise connected then there is always one lifting. Is there an example of a continuous $f$ from a simply connected but not locally arcwise connected without lifting? I have encountered some examples where the subset condition isn't met, but the only non locally arcwise connected spaces that I know are "the comb" and the topologist's sine. How could I get such a function?
Here Does simply connected implies locally pathwise-connected? they talk about this condition but no example is given.

Oh, it was me who gave the answer to the linked question. Let's go! :)
Consider a variant of the Warsaw circle:

We take topologist's sine curve and wrap it around. But on the left we end it with a single end. So all sufficiently small neighbourhoods of that single point are disconnected. And only of that point. This construction works with other variants, but with this one it is simpler to explain.
So this will be our $Y$. Now we consider $X=S^1$ to be the standard circle. There is an obvious continuous bijection $f:Y\to X$ which just collapses this Warsaw circle into the circle. It is pretty much just projection.
Now it is not hard to see that unlike $S^1$ our $Y$ is actually simply connected. The reason is that no loop $S^1\to Y$ can have entire $Y$ in is image, since an image of a locally connected space through quotient map is necessarily locally connected. And $Y$ is not. And if $S^1\to Y$ is not surjective, then it has to factorize through $[0,1]$ and thus is homotopic to a constant map.
Therefore the "$f_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0))\subset \rho_*(\pi_1(\hat{X},\hat{x}_0))$" condition is automatically satisfied by all $f$, including our projection.
Now take $\hat{X}=\mathbb{R}$ with the universal covering $\rho:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$. So can $f$ be lifted to $\hat{f}:Y\to\mathbb{R}$? If so, then $\rho\circ \hat{f}=f$ condition together with $f$ being injective, implies injectivity of $\hat{f}$.
However no continuous function $g:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ is injective. If $a,b\in im(g)$, $a< b$, then I can pick $x\in g^{-1}(a)$ and $y\in g^{-1}(b)$. Of course $x\neq y$ and the removal of those two points divides the Warsaw circle into two disjoint connected pieces say $C_x,C_y$ with $\{x,y\}$ as boundary of each. But then $[a,b]\subseteq g(C_x\cup\{x,y\})$ and $[a,b]\subseteq g(C_y\cup \{x,y\})$ simply by connectedness. Which means that if $a<b$ then $g^{-1}(c)$ necessarily has to have at least two points for any $a<c<b$.
By the way, this is exactly the same argument why there is no continuous injective map $S^1\to \mathbb{R}$. And indeed, the identity map $S^1\to S^1$ (which corresponds to our projection) also doesn't have a lift $S^1\to\mathbb{R}$ by the same argument. However $S^1$ is not simply connected, and in fact the identity doesn't satisfy "$f_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0))\subset \rho_*(\pi_1(\hat{X},\hat{x}_0))$" condition. That was the motivation for picking the Warsaw circle.
